# Adding shadedreliefarchive imagery to QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, shaded-relief

I'm trying to add some relief imagery that is found at [shadedreliefarchive.com](http://www.shadedreliefarchive.com)

Specifically, I'm trying to add the SEAsia one found [here](http://www.shadedreliefarchive.com/Southeast_Asia_CIA.html).

I've tried making a custom CRS to match the details found on the page, but the units are way off and I'm not sure which units should be used anyway.  My definition is below.  Can anybody help?  Either with the correct already defined CRS or the user string for a custom CRS?

```
+proj=lcc +lat_1=10 +lat_2=21 +lat_0=17 +lon_0=103 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
```

Comment: is this even possible? seems the "Georeferencing: None" indicates these are just 'pictures'...

Comment: They are.  But I was wondering if I could get a close approximation.

Comment: In that case you could georeference them yourself using the QGIS georeferencer... its an easy tool to use!

Comment: That worked. Much better than defining a custom projection.  Forgot about that tool.  Thanks.

Comment: alright great! Glad to help!

Comment: You want to add an answer for some reputation points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've mentioned, the image contains very little georeferencing information.

And, as you're only looking for a 'close approximation', you could bring the image into QGIS and use the georeferencer. It's an easy to use tool, and hey - you might even get the image georeferenced closer than you think!

Here's a great tutorial: http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/02/tutorial-georeferencing-topo-sheets.html

Let me know if you have any more questions!